# Why is 3-digit credit card security code needed to pay already charged bill?

Tags: credit-card

Why does a medical billing company, for services already delivered, need the 3-digit code on the back of my credit card when sending credit card info by mail or phone

Comment: I think you're going to add a little more detail.  Has the bill already been paid?  Is this payment for a subsequent bill?

Comment: Lower fees an their end and to protect you and them

Comment: Whether or not the devices were already delivered doesn't change that fact that the bill isn't paid until you provide payment. You provide payment by sending your credit card details, which include the 3-digit CVV code.

Comment: I don't believe they are allowed to request the CVV code by mail -- it's something that should never be recorded or written down, just transactional use for internet or phone orders. I'll try to find a reference...

Comment: Follow-up -- technically asking for CVV by mail is allowed, but the paper is supposed to be shredded/destroyed after initial authorization and the CVV cannot be permanently recorded anywhere. I have a feeling this practice is not followed as often as it should be.

Answer (score 5):

The CVV code adds an extra layer of protection. It essentially proves that you have the [physical card](https://www.cvvnumber.com/) in your possession. In addition, it's used as a [fraud prevention method](https://www.nerdwallet.com/blog/credit-cards/find-credit-card-cvv-number/), so that in the event your card number is compromised, hackers won't be able to charge anything from merchants that require that number.

Comment: To add to this, the billing company is not permitted to store your CVV number, so they have to ask you for it again for each transaction.